# Error message shows on terminal but not on browser console

Tags: next.js, graphql, prisma, apollo-server

## The bug

I was using `apollo-server-micro` and I was able to display error messages just fine. After moving to `@as-integrations/next` all error messages display as `Internal Server Error` which is not really helpful to the users.

The website works normally, however, the only problem is that it is no longer showing the error messages that I throw.

#### Production

In production, error messages are all `Internal Server Error` with this error object:

[image]

However, on my terminal, it shows that I do have an error that is `Error: Username already taken`, but this is not showing on the browser console, therefore I cannot display the error message to the client.

[image]

---

#### Development

`Error: Username already taken` is the error message I want to show on the client, it appears on my terminal but not on the browser console, and it looks like `@apollo/server` is the cause?:

[image]

Browser console returns `HTML` code as error response and the error message (`Error: Username already taken`) is not showing in this error object:

[image]

---

### The code

I use `Next.js` serverless functions for my `GraphQL` (`TypeGraphQL`) API with `Apollo Server` (`@as-integrations/next`) and `@tanstack/react-query` with `graphql-request`

#### Apollo Server

`/api/graphql`

```js
export interface TContext {
  prisma: typeof prisma;
  id?: string;
}

const schema = await buildSchema({
  resolvers: [UserResolver, MessageResolver],
});

const server = new ApolloServer({
  schema,
  plugins: [responseCachePlugin()],
});

const _handler = startServerAndCreateNextHandler(server, {
  context: async (req) => {
    const session = await getSession({ req });
    const id = session?.user?.id;
    return { prisma, id };
  },
});

export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  res.setHeader(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
    process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL as string
  );
  res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 's-maxage=86400');

  return _handler(req, res);
}
```

---

#### GraphQL Resolver

This is the resolver that throws the error `Username already taken`:

```js
  @Mutation(() => String)
  async editUsername(
    @Arg('username', () => String) username: string,
    @Ctx() { prisma, id }: TContext
  ): Promise<String> {
    const usernameRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;

    try {
      if (!usernameRegex.test(username)) {
        throw new Error('Username must be alphanumeric');
      }

      const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({ where: { username } });

      if (user) {
        throw new Error('Username already taken');
      }

      await prisma.user.update({
        where: { id },
        data: { username },
      });
      return 'Username edited';
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      throw err;
    }
  }
```

---

### Query Client

I used `graphql-codegen` for the SDK

```js
const gqlClient = new GraphQLClient(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GQL_ENDPOINT ?? '');
export const {
  getUser,
  addReply,
  createUser,
  deleteUser,
  sendMessage,
  editMessage,
  editUsername,
  deleteMessage,
  changePassword,
  editUserMessage,
  getSeenMessages,
  getSentMessages,
  getRecentMessages,
} = getSdk(gqlClient);

export const queryClient = new QueryClient({
  queryCache: new QueryCache({
    onError: (error) => {
      toast.error(JSON.stringify(error, null, 2));
      console.log(error);
    },
  }),

  mutationCache: new MutationCache({
    onError: (error) => {
      toast.error(JSON.stringify(error, null, 2));
      console.log(error);
    },
  }),
  defaultOptions: {
    queries: {
      refetchOnMount: false,
      refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
      refetchOnReconnect: false,
    },
  },
});
```

---

### What I tried

Since I get the error below, I thought that `Apollo Server` is the culprit, so I tried downgrading to other versions of `4.x.x` but still didn't work. Also tried updating other dependencies like `graphql-request` and others.

```bash
web:dev: Unexpected error processing request: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'code')
web:dev: - error Error [TypeError]: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'code')
web:dev:     at enrichError (file:///home/xfi/projects/nextjs/umamin/node_modules/@apollo/server/dist/esm/errorNormalize.js:31:43)
web:dev:     at file:///home/xfi/projects/nextjs/umamin/node_modules/@apollo/server/dist/esm/errorNormalize.js:16:28
web:dev:     at Array.map (<anonymous>)
web:dev:     at normalizeAndFormatErrors (file:///home/xfi/projects/nextjs/umamin/node_modules/@apollo/server/dist/esm/errorNormalize.js:10:33)
web:dev:     at ApolloServer.errorResponse (file:///home/xfi/projects/nextjs/umamin/node_modules/@apollo/server/dist/esm/ApolloServer.js:530:53)
web:dev:     at ApolloServer.executeHTTPGraphQLRequest (file:///home/xfi/projects/nextjs/umamin/node_modules/@apollo/server/dist/esm/ApolloServer.js:526:25) {
web:dev:   digest: undefined
web:dev: }
```

---

I thought that my `Next.js` handler was the issue, so I removed the extra stuff that I did but still did not work:

```js
const server = new ApolloServer({
  schema,
  plugins: [responseCachePlugin()],
});

export default startServerAndCreateNextHandler(server);
```

---

I also tried making a simple resolver that throws an error:

```js
  @Query(() => String)
  hello(): string {
    throw new Error('Some error.');
  }
```

---

This is what I get as a response in `Apollo Sandbox` (`http://localhost:3000/api/graphql`)

```json
{
  "data": {},
  "error": {
    "message": "JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data",
    "stack": ""
  }
}
```